Record and mock server response to test selenium package
I'm writing a web automation package using python and selenium.
The target server can't be accessed outside my company's local network. Therefore, if I don't run unit tests inside the company, selenium webdriver can't get responses from the server and my tests will fail.
Is there any way to record and save server responses so I can pass the tests when I'm not connected to that network?
I'm using pytest and I looked up mocking but I don't want to write a full response. I would like to record the real response from the server which is not online on the internet if possible.
